# Pentaho/Pivot4j - Failed to retrieve cube list

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, pivot4j

I'm doing a course from Coursera of Data Warehouse and I'm facing some problems with Pivot4j plugin.

There is a word document explaining how to install Pentaho. I've followed all the instructions, some of them are:

- Install Java Runtime Environment (JRE7)
- Download Pentaho BI Plugin stable release 0.9 (pivot4j-pentaho-0.9-plugin.zip).

I've started the web interface for the Pentaho BI server in my browser and navigate to the address http://localhost:8080/ after that I logged as administrator and everything was working properly. I clicked on Create new > Pivot4j View and a new screen appeared to me select the catalog and the cube. However when I select any catalog option the system return an error as showed in the image below:

I really appreciate any help.

[Pivot4j Error - Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXAmb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the version 1.0-snapshot instead of the v0.9?